# Connecting two Columns with list Elements for Pivot in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns (keys, values) which I want to pivot with pandas.

After importing, my dataset looks like this:

|  | Work Center | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | k1 | a, | 1, |
| 1 | k2 | a,b, | 3,5, |
| 2 | k1 | c,a, | 7.5,5, |

I want to get this:

| Work Center | key.a | key.b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| k1 | sum val a | sum val b |
| .. | .. | .. |

Comment: Have you made any attempts at solving it by yourself? If so please include those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can `split` on `key` and `value` columns and `explode` them to rows

```py
df_ = (df
   .set_index(['Work Center'])
   .apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
   .replace('', pd.NA)
   .dropna(subset=['key'])
)
```

```
  Work Center key value
0          k1   a     1
2          k2   a     3
3          k2   b     5
5          k1   c   7.5
6          k1   a     5
```

Then use `pivot_table` to pivot it

```py
df_['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df_['value'])

df_ = (df_
   .pivot_table(index='Work Center', columns='key', values='value', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
   .add_prefix('key.')
)
```

```
print(df_)

key          key.a  key.b  key.c
Work Center
k1               6      0    7.5
k2               3      5    0.0
```